# How to shortcut (nmap) windo command expression?

Tags: vim

For closing all quickfix windows, I use the following vim command expression:

```
:windo if &buftype == 'quickfix' || &buftype == 'locationlist' | lclose | endif
```

Whenever I try to shortcut it like:

```
nmap <S-q> :let @a = "%:windo if &buftype == 'quickfix' || &buftype == 'locationlist' | lclose | endif"
```

by using `nmap` in my init.vim, I got an error:

> E749: empty buffer
>
> E488: Trailing characters

How to solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Explanation

The `|` is a *command separator*; unfortunately (this is a common pitfall), it also ends any `:map` command, and the remainder is interpreted immediately, instead of being part of the mapping.

`:help map-bar` lists three different solutions; the most common is using the special `<Bar>` notation instead of `|`.

#### Your mapping

```
nmap <S-q> :let @a = "%:windo if &buftype == 'quickfix' <Bar><Bar> &buftype == 'locationlist' <Bar> lclose <Bar> endif"
```

- Is the `%:windo` a typo? The `%` is suspicious.
- The mapping is missing the trailing `<CR>`; it will linger until you press `<Enter>` yourself. Is that intended?
- Why do you assign the commands to register `a` instead of executing it?
- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- `'buftype'` is always `quickfix`, also for location lists; you can drop the second branch in the test.

```
noremap <S-q> :windo if &buftype == 'quickfix' <Bar> lclose <Bar> endif<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Now I changed it to: noremap <S-q> :windo if &buftype == 'quickfix' <Bar><Bar> &buftype == 'locationlist' <Bar> lclose <Bar> endif<CR>

Comment: Great! I found another nitpick: `buftype` cannot contain `locationlist`; you can remove the check for that. If that solves the problem, please accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it.

Comment: I would use `:cclose` & `:lcose` instead of using `:windo`. e.g. `nnoremap <silent> <c-w>z <c-w>z:cclose<cr>lclose<cr>`